# [Nuxt, i18n, Vuex]: How to access this.$i18n.locales from store getter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, nuxt-i18n

I'm building a web app using Nuxt v2.15 and @nuxtjs/i18n v7.2. I'm using Vuex for state management. In my global state, I want to create a getter that returns a value based on `this.$i18n.locale`.

What is the best way to access the current app context, which has `$i18n` attached to it, in my Vuex getter method?

**nuxt.config.js**

```js
export default {
  modules: [
    "@nuxtjs/i18n", // https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/
  ],
  i18n: {
    locales: { /* configuration */ },
    defaultLocale: "en",
    detectBrowserLanguage: {
      fallbackLocale: "en",
      redirectOn: "root",
    },
    langDir: "~/locales/",
    vueI18n: {
      fallbackLocale: "en",
      messages: { /* translation data */ },
    },
  },
};
```

**store/index.js**

```js
export const state = () => ({
  // Root module for Vuex store: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/store/
});

export const getters = {
  loginOpts() {
    const locale = this.$i18n.locale;
    const uiLocales = [locale];
    if (locale === "zh") {
      uiLocales.push("zh-CN");
    }
    return { params: { ui_locales: uiLocales } };
  },
};
```

**components/login.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn v-if="$auth.loggedIn" @click="$auth.logout()">Sign Out</v-btn>
    <v-btn v-else @click="$auth.loginWith('auth0', $store.getters.loginOpts)">Sign In</v-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "Login",
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["loginOpts"]),
  },
};
</script>
```

**What I expect**

I expect to be able to access `this.$i18n` from a Vuex getter, or to have some means of doing so.

**What actually happens**

In the getter method, `this` is undefined.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$i18n')
```

**What I've tried**

I see [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access) that a getter is passed four arguments: `state`, `getters`, `rootState`, and `rootGetters`.

I've tried:

- RTFM for Vuex [State](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html), [Getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access), and [Nuxt i18n](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/options-reference/#vuex)
- accessing `state.$i18n`
- adding `$i18n: this.$i18n` to the root state

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem last week where I absolutely needed to use i18n inside a vuex getter.

I wouldn't recommend this as its probably not the most performant thing in the world but it worked for me and solved a huge problem while I was working on a government application.

**components/login.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn v-if="$auth.loggedIn" @click="$auth.logout()">Sign Out</v-btn>
    <v-btn v-else @click="$auth.loginWith('auth0', theLoginOpts)">Sign In</v-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "Login",
  data() {
    return {
        theLoginOpts: $store.getters.loginOpts(this) // The secret sauce
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["loginOpts"]),
  },
};
</script>
```

**store/index.js**

```
export const state = () => ({
  // Root module for Vuex store: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/store/
});

export const getters = {
  loginOpts: (state) => (app) => { // App is the secret sauce from earlier
    const locale = app.$i18n.locale;
    const uiLocales = [locale];
    if (locale === "zh") {
      uiLocales.push("zh-CN");
    }
    return { params: { ui_locales: uiLocales } };
  },
};
```

Comment: Thank you. That certainly is one way to do it, but I was hoping there was a more “built-in” approach. This is a workaround and gets the job done, but something about passing an argument to a getter doesn’t seem right to me…

Comment: Passing a param to a getter is something that can be done but is indeed a bit weird. Passing the actual context is even more hacky tbh.

Answer (score 1):

After digging through docs, experimenting, and discussing with the folks who were kind enough to offer answers here, it is clear that `i18n` is not directly accessible in a Vuex getter method, despite the fact that [@nuxt/i18n registers a Vuex module](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/options-reference#vuex) called `i18n` and everything I've read about [Vuex modules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#module-local-state) suggests this should be possible.

I did however come across the docs for [@nuxt/i18n callbacks](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/callbacks/), which led me to create a small [plugin](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/plugins/) that sets the value of `locale` and `uiLocales` in the global state using a [mutation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html).

The end result looks like this:

**nuxt.config.js**

```js
export default {
  modules: [
    "@nuxtjs/i18n", // https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/
  ],
  plugins: [
    "~/plugins/i18n.js",
  ],
  i18n: {
    locales: { /* configuration */ },
    defaultLocale: "en",
    detectBrowserLanguage: {
      fallbackLocale: "en",
      redirectOn: "root",
    },
    langDir: "~/locales/",
    vueI18n: {
      fallbackLocale: "en",
      messages: { /* translation data */ },
    },
  },
};
```

**plugins/i18n.js**

```js
export function findLocaleConfig (i18n, locale) {
  return (
    i18n.locales.find(({ iso, code }) => [iso, code].includes(locale)) || {}
  );
}

export default function ({ app }) {
  app.store.commit("localeChange", findLocaleConfig(app.i18n, app.i18n.locale));

  app.i18n.onLanguageSwitched = (oldLocale, newLocale) => {
    app.store.commit("localeChange", findLocaleConfig(app.i18n, newLocale));
  };
}
```

**store/index.js**

```js
export const state = () => ({
  locale: null,
  uiLocales: [],
});

export const mutations = {
  localeChange(state, locale) {
    state.locale = locale.code;
    state.uiLocales = [locale.code, locale.iso];
  },
};
```

**components/login.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn v-if="$auth.loggedIn" @click="$auth.logout()">Sign Out</v-btn>
    <v-btn v-else @click="$auth.loginWith('auth0', loginOpts)">Sign In</v-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Login",
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  computed: {
    loginOpts() {
      const uiLocales = this.$store.state.uiLocales;
      return { params: { ui_locales: uiLocales } };
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer if it solved your issue! :)

Comment: It solved my issue, but I feel like it didn’t answer my question. I’d still like to know how to access the i18n Vuex module state from the root state, or understand why I cannot. Was holding out to see if someone knew.

Answer (score 0):

You can access a the locale in an Vuex action with: `this.app.i18n.locale`.
This cannot be accessed in a `state` or `getter` (a getter is a not a place for it anyway IMO).

PS: The above means that means that you can access this value anywhere you have access to the [Nuxt context](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/context-helpers).

Comment: Thank you. I’m curious why you think a getter is not the place for it. The user chooses a locale, which I would consider to be part of the application state. I’m trying to create a globally accessible computed value based on that state. How should this be implemented, in your opinion?

Comment: @ShaunScovil just access the vuex state. A getter is when you want to massage the state in some way, like filter an array based on something or alike. Here, you can conditionally (`zh-CN`) set your locale and access it afterwards, no need for a vuex getter. More info in the official docs: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#getters

Comment: I see. I think the problem is that @nuxt/i18n is not using Vuex to store the locale state, and is instead storing it in app.$i18n. Maybe there is something I can do about that…

Comment: It can totally be stored in Vuex, check the various options. @ShaunScovil

Comment: I’ve read the docs and there is an option for using Vuex that is enabled by default, but as far as I can tell it is inaccessible in the getter which prompted me to ask this question on SO. Docs: https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/options-reference/#vuex

Comment: My initial answer is still valid @ShaunScovil

Answer (score 0):

The simple way we did in our project is like below:
In component computed prop

```
teamsForSelector() {
  return this.$store.getters['company/teamsForSelector'](this.$i18n);
}
```

and in state getters

```
teamsForSelector: (state) => ($i18n) => {
const teamsForSelector = state.teams.map((team) => {
  return {
    id: team.teamUid,
    label: team.teamName,
  };
});
teamsForSelector.unshift({
  id: 'all-teams',
  label: $i18n.t('key'),
});
```

return teamsForSelector;
}

Answer (score 0):

In Nuxt 2 if your page renders on frontend you can try to access `$i18n` using `window.$nuxt` or simply `$nuxt`:

```
export const getters = {
  loginOpts() {
    const locale = window.$nuxt.$i18n.locale;
    ...
  },
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).